# diagonal split is not aligned in table

Tags: tables

diagonal split is not proper aligned. how to align it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{9em}|p{9.89em}|p{16.165em}|p{12.28em}|p{8.165em}|p{9.945em}|p{6.665em}|p{8.165em}|}
    \toprule
    \textbf{\diagbox[]{Mobility Model}{Parameter}} & \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{f} & \textbf{g} \\
   \midrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: (i) your table is to wide that can be fit in the text width, (ii) `diagbox` doesn't work with rules from `booktabs` you should consider to use standard `\hline`

Comment: i had also use \backslashbox but that is also not working

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{9em}|p{9.89em}|p{16.165em}|p{12.28em}|p{8.165em}|p{9.945em}|p{6.665em}|p{8.165em}|}
    \hline\textbf{\backslash {Mobility Model}{Parameter}} & \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{f} & \textbf{g} \\\end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}

Comment: diagonally split cell (regardless which package you use for them) doesn't work with rules from `booktabs` package, because they add some vertical space above and below rules. you have , as i see, three choices: (i) not use diagonally split cells (as i suggest in answer below), (ii) use ordinary  `\hline` for horizontal lines in table and (ii) remove vertical space around rules from `booktabs`.

Answer (score 3):

i would not use `diagbox`. to my opinion is more clear and answer the following design of your table:

[image]

which is generated by:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c*{7}{X}}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2.4}*{\textbf{Mobility Model}}
        &   \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{Parameter}}  \\
        \cmidrule{2-8}
        & \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{f} & \textbf{g} \\
    \midrule
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

i select `tabularx` table environment ad assume, that all columns except first have equal width.  if you would provide some row of table body (that we can see size of other cells contents) than i will be able to suggest different column width.

**addendum:**
off course, proposed solution works at any columns type. for example, if you use `p{...}` columns, than the table definition can be:

```
    \begin{tabular}{l*{7}{p{3em}}}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2.4}*{\textbf{Mobility Model}}
        &   \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{Parameter}}  \\
        \cmidrule{2-8}
        & \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{f} & \textbf{g} \\
    \midrule
    \end{tabular}
```

similary you can select column types as you need (as i mentioned bewof, the contents of table is not known to me, so  i can't help you in the design columns types).

this also work with `longtable`. only you need accordingly design heads for those table

Comment: yes it is a good option sir,thanks , but will the same work with \longtable if it is a long table of multipage table

Comment: @monika, suggested approach works at any kind of table.

Comment: the other cells are like \begin{table}[htbp]\centering \begin{tabular}{|p{9em}|p{9.89em}|p{16.165em}|p{12.28em}|p{8.165em}|p{9.945em}|p{6.665em}|p{8.165em}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{\diaghead{\theadfont Diag ColumnmnHead II}%
    {Mobility\\ Model}{Para-\\meter}} & \textbf{Basic Description} & \textbf{Adaptability for AANETs} & \textbf{Support to higher node mobility and Frequent topology updates} & \textbf{Safety parameters} & \textbf{Mechanical and aerodynamic constraint} & \textbf{Degree of Randomness} & \textbf{Applications} \\
    \hlineend{tabularx}%\end{table}%\end{document}

Comment: @monika, i told you that this selection of columns width cannot be fit in page size. you should reduce their widths! and please, be so kind and edit your question, add this information there and show result, which you obtain.

Comment: \begin{document}\begin{table}[htbp]\centering\begin{tabular}{|p{3em}|p{5em}|p{4em}|p{5em}|p{5em}|p{4em}|p{4em}|p{4em}|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Mobility Model}}
      &   \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{Parameter}}  \\
            \cmidrule{2-8}& \textbf{Basic Description} & \textbf{Adaptability for AANETs} & \textbf{Support to higher node mobility and Frequent topology updates} & \textbf{Safety parameters} & \textbf{Mechanical and aerodynamic constraint} & \textbf{Degree of Randomness} & \textbf{Applications} \\ \hline end{tabular}%\label{tab:addlabel}%\end{table}%\end{document}

Comment: still multi row data crossing the column

Comment: @monika, please, please add this information to your question that they can see other members of site too. also in comments are not readable well. so far i can only conclude, that you have many issues with your table, which aren't related to your question. you should consider to ask new question with this new problems. it seems that https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options can help you.